# How to replace current fragment with fragment of same class using Navigation component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

Let's say I have possible routes:

A->**B**->C->C. Here when user press back I want to go back to **B**

A->**D**->C->C. Here when user press back I want to go back to **D**

How to replace **C** with new instance of **C** without specifying explicitly popUpTo in the action?

Comment: If you only want one instance of C on the top of the stack, is there a reason you aren't using `launchSingleTop`?

Comment: I tried using launchSingleTop. With is it set to true, nothing happens, the same fragment with wrong data remains open.

Comment: Please include your code